# Rails Integration Testing: Is Capybara necessary for interacting with Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I'm new to testing in Rails and I'm trying to get into integration testing. I'm working with a Rails 4.2 project and I've written some simple tests in the default Minitest framework. I've quickly got to the point where I need to interact with javascript in the html by clicking a button and verifying that a modal appears.

From the research that I've done, it doesn't seem to be possible to to do anything like this with the syntax and driver that comes with Minitest. In order to do this I need to use Caypbara or something equivalent.

Firstly - Is that really the case? is there really no way to test Javascript with the default setup in Rails?

Assuming that is the case, I've pulled in Capybara to my project to utilize it's DSL and drivers for testing Javascript, but in doing so, it has rendered my initial tests useless. They no longer work as the Capybara DSL overwrites the `assert_select` method, forcing me to use Capybara syntax for writing tests - not something that I'm against, I'm just figuring this out.

So it seems like that if I ever want to test Javascript, then I need to use Capybara? and if I pull in Capybara then all my tests need to use Capybara syntax? If this is true, then it seems like I should just use Capybara from the get-go on all projects.

Comment: its not exclusive, you can have both testunit and capybara tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

- There's no way to test Javascript with the default setup in Rails. You'll need Capybara because it implements a [smart wait](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends) when the DOM might be modified by Javascript, and a Capybara driver that can interpret Javascript.
- You can choose which of your test objects use Capybara by `include Capybara::DSL` only on those objects. You don't need to include it in all of your tests.

Now, I wouldn't recommend that half of your integration tests use Capybara and half of them don't. It will eventually confuse you or somebody else.

This is the test setup I would recommend:

1. Extract some of the logic from your Controllers or Models into Service Objects and test them with `require 'test_helper'`, which doesn't load the whole Rails stack. It will make these tests very fast.
2. Keep the rest of your unit tests in plain minitest (of course, you don't need Capybara for them) and running as fast as possible. You'll still need to `require 'rails_helper'` to load the Rails stack to test Models, Views and Controllers.
3. Use Capybara for all of your Integration tests. These should be fewer compared to your unit tests and will run very slow since you'll be using a Javascript driver. You can still choose which driver to use on which integration tests, to avoid using the slower Javascript driver when you don't need it.

To include Capybara on your integration tests:

```
# test/rails_helper.rb
require "capybara/rails"

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

To change the current driver:

```
# test/integration/some_integration_test.rb
class SomeIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # the default Capybara driver is :rack_test
  test "use javascript driver" do
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist # which uses phantomjs
    # visit, clicks and assertions
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

The `Capybara.current_driver` and `Capybara.use_default_driver` can be extracted into a module and put into `setup` and `teardown` methods if you want to reuse it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. This explains everything.

Comment: Coincidentally, Rails 5.1 was released two days before your comment and now it comes with Capybara.

Comment: You're right, it reads very cool: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#system-tests